# How do I add a space between my image and title text in yaml on Quarto?

Tags: yaml, latex, rstudio, quarto

I want to create a spacing between the image and title that are in my Quarto doc.

I have tried to use vspace but it did not work.
This is my YAML so far:

```
---
title: |  
  ![](my-image.png){width=5in}  
  Title
subtitle: "`r Company`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_width: 8   # Set the width of all plots in inches
    fig_height: 6  # Set the height of all plots in inches
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    number-sections: false
    colorlinks: true
    linkcolor: blue
    mainfont: Myriad Pro
    header-includes:
      - "\\usepackage{fontspec}"
      - "\\newfontfamily\\tfont{Montserrat}"
      - "\\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\\tfont}"
      - "\\addtokomafont{disposition}{\\tfont}"  # Change font for section headings
      - "\\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.75in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}"
fontsize: 14pt
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a few `\linebreak`s after the image tag.

```
---
title: |  
  ![](my-image.png){width=5in}\linebreak\linebreak\linebreak
  Title
subtitle: "`r Company`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_width: 8   # Set the width of all plots in inches
    fig_height: 6  # Set the height of all plots in inches
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    number-sections: false
    colorlinks: true
    linkcolor: blue
fontsize: 14pt
---
```

[image]